# Any good tutorials/explanations of subpools and pools in-general?

Tags: memory-management, ada, pool

I'm looking for something to help me understand pools, and the new Ada 2012 sub-pools. I've seen the [rationale example](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rat/html/Rat12-6-4.html) and the example at [Adapower](http://www.adapower.com/index.php?Command=Class&ClassID=Advanced&CID=222) but I find they're somewhat lacking in giving you a good understanding of what's going on.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem you want to solve?

Comment: Not particularly; I'm looking into it as more of a learning thing than as a "I have a real-world problem." (That's rather unhelpful, I know.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absent knowledge of a definitive text or particular use-case, here are a few resources:

- [*§13.4 Storage Pool Management*](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/95rat/rat95html/rat95-p2-13.html#4), Ada 95 Rationale.
- [*§6.4 Access types and storage pools*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rat/html/Rat12-6-4.html), Ada 2012 Rationale.
- [*§13.11.6 Storage Subpool Example*](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-13-11-6.html), Ada 2012 Reference Manual.
- [*Memory Management with Storage Pools*](http://www.adapower.com/index.php?Command=Class&ClassID=Advanced&CID=222), AdaPower.
- [*Arena storage pool*](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Arena_storage_pool#Ada), RosettaCode.
- [*§11.10.1 Storage Pools*](http://www.pegasoft.ca/resources/boblap/11.html#11.10), [*The Big Online Book of Linux Ada Programming*](http://www.pegasoft.ca/resources/boblap/book.html).
- [*Gem #77: Where did my memory go?*](http://www.adacore.com/adaanswers/gems/gem-77/), AdaCore.
- [Usenet example and thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.ada/VhMaXDrMZ44/573cLOcVEiUJ).